# Pass the textbox value from Jade to node.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

How can I send the textbox value from Jade to node.js

```
form(action='/send', method='POST')
              pre

                   label From   :

                   input(type='text',id="Fromtime", name='f1_time')
                   br
                   label To     :
                   input(type='text', id="Totime", name='t1_tdime')
                   br
                   br
                   br
                   label On :
                   input(type='radio', name='on', id='amount_0')
                   label Off:
                   input(type='radio', name='off', id='amount_1')
                   br
                   br
                   br
                   input(type='submit', value='Send !')
```

how can I use the value of the text in app.js by using module express

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.js

```
app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.f1_time); // show the value of the text box
});
```

[Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: I appreciate your help.
I tried this, but it didn't work with me.It gives empty line.Also, if I put it as follow:
   app.post('/send', function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body); // show the value of the text box
      });
it gives me {}